# Why physical emmulator doesn't show?

Tags: android, adb

I downloaded Android Studio. When I ran the physical Android device, it shows "Unable to connect to ADB. Check the event Log for possible issues.Verify that your local host entry is pointed to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 for IPv4 or IPv6, respectively."

HELP!

I already downloaded the Android API, Google SDK manager and system service. I don't know why I did that.

Comment: could you add the log into the question ?

Comment: what version of android studio dou you have ?

Comment: android 3.4 beta

Comment: It would be helpful if you show as a picture of your problem. A picture worth one thousand words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio 3.4 version,if you are using windows then follow these steps may be its help you

1.Download Platform tools from here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.0-windows.zip

2.Extract downloaded zip file

3.Go To location "C:\Users\your_computer_user_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" and Delete "Platform tools" folder

4.Copy and Paste downloaded platform tools folder to above location

5.Now Go to your android studio and "clean" and "Rebuild" your project and run

good luck!